# Is there any way to create custom button in Magnific Popup Caption?

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

Is there any possibility to have custom button/div/p in Magnific Popup Caption, because only thing that I can actually add is caption by giving title to .

I don't have any example, working copy or something to show code.

I am just curious is there a way to do it and example of it, if there is a way.

Thanks

Comment: http://codepen.io/collection/nLcqo/

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved my day!